# Retain Picklist value field on Lightning Component coming from Screen Flow

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, screen-flow

I have below scenario :  I have a quick action on Order for "Cancel Sales Order" which pops up screen flow it has 2 sections , 1st section is an aura component which has 2 picklist fields ( A with values 1,2,3 and dependent picklist field on that, B with values 1A,2A,3A ) and 2nd section has a date field "Cancel Date"(not in aura ,directly used in screen flow" . So whenever User selects the values 1 from A field and 1A from B field and keeps Cancel Date blank and hit Save, a screen shows up a text message from the flow saying that Cancel Date is missing as per requirement. But in doing so the values entered in A and B fields are erased, I would like to retain those values in any case(I tried to create a attribute in component and pass it to Flow's output variable and show this again to component, however it doesn't show up in the picklist , however I can it in the alert) How should I proceed with this, any help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck with this for long time.